# How can I push data to an array within an object?

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure how I can push data to the "data" property within "decData".

```
        var decData = {
            labels: [],
            datasets: [

                {
                    fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                    strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    data: []
                }
            ]
        }
```

Here is the code I'm using that isn't working

```
        decData.datasets.data.push(dayProfit);
```

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? The error is

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined

Comment: Try `decData.datasets[0].data.push(dayProfit)` since datasets is an array.

Comment: Wow, how did I miss that. Thanks a bunch mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `datasets` object is an array, so you would need to address an element within the array:

```
decData.datasets[0].data.push(dayProfit);
```

Answer (score 0):

I your code, `datasets` is an array. Try this:

```
decData.datasets[0].data.push("stuff");
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can always add a push method to your object:

```
var decData = {
        ...
        push: function (value){
            this.datasets[0].data.push(value);
        }
    }
```

now you can use this method:

```
decData.push(dayProfit);
```

But you have have to ask yourself the question, is the first data set the only place you want to push data to? cause this is what the code does.